# Has the speed of animals changed over time?

Tags: evolution

I am not a biologist but always had the following questions:

Evolution theory says that the fittest of the fittest pass their genes on. Perhaps an oversimplification, but this would mean that slower lions would be less likely to pass on their genes. For example, lions that are slower would eat less, become weaker, be less attractive to their mates ... and therefore, be less likely to pass on their genes compared to lions that could run faster. And evolution theory also would suggest that the speed of a lion cub would be statistically closer to its parents - faster lions are more likely to produce faster lion cubs and vice versa. Obviously, there is probably a terminal speed - that is, lions wont eventually run at the speed of light, and likely plateau at some speed after many evolutions ... and then the rate of increase will likely be negligible from generation to generation.

This brings me to my question:

- Do we know if animals like lions are running faster than they were 1 million years ago?
- If we define a new ratio variable as R = (average speed of lions)/(average speed of gazelles) ... do we know if this variable R has remained relatively constant over the past 1 million years?

Thanks!

Notes:

- These animals have mutated millions of years ago and their current form might have mutated from their old form. Therefore, a given lion from a  certain species 10 million years ago might be a new species of lion, making any comparison somewhat irrelevant (i.e. comparing apples to oranges)
- We assume that animals become faster each year - but its possible that they no longer need to be as fast due to environmental changes (e.g. deforestation caused by humans has changed the habitat of their prey and the prey is easier to catch, and requires less energy to chase).

Comment: fitness is relative not absolute, thick insulation is a great adaptation in the artic and horrible in the desert. every adaptation has its cost. the more you are adapted for speed the less you are adapted for anything else, like strength or robustness, just look at cheetah. super fast but easily bodied by basically any other predator.

Comment: Modern lions are less than 1 million years old. Last common ancestor ~500,000 years ago. Also - fastest =! fittest evolutionarily speaking for lions. They are mostly stealth hunters - jump and pounce, or short charge.